# Fitting time resolved data with a convolution

Tags: laser, data-analysis

I want to fit experimental data of a time dependent Signal. The Signal is the result of a concentration convolved with a pulse. But the question is more in general, so I hope the picture below will help.

[image: Convolution of Signal with pulse]

As you see, the values of the convolution drop off at the start and end. This is correct since also the signal drops to zero. Howevever, my experimental data would start on 1 (normalized background) and would rise to some unknown value. But of course I can only take a finite amount of data. When I now use my fit function, it will also drop off at the start and end, but that is not how it should look like to have a good fit.
Here is also a plot of my problem specifically:

[image: Data and fit]

Here the fit is a convolution of the (modeled) concentration with the (modeled) laser pulse to estimate the real data.

My solution would be to define the fit function, so that it gives a zero where I dont have full overlap of the data and the pulse and modify my experimental data (which are basically lost then) accordingly, i.e. set them at those x-values to zero as well.

Or I could give a high sigma/uncertainty to the values that drop of, to neglect them while fitting.

Since time resolved measurements need this, I wonder what is the usual way to go about that ? Or any other solutions that are a bit neater?

Comment: Is there something keeping you from subtracting the background before fitting your curve?

Comment: No there is not, but then the problem would keep existing for the end of the signal. But you are right, that would sort of solve "half" of the problem

Comment: It seems that if you have data that doesn't go back to 0, and you have no reason to believe it should go back to 0, then the fit function you are using ist just not adequate for the thing it is supposed to model. Am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: Well, at the current moment it is not adequate, but that *is* my Problem. The reason it is not adeqaute is, that the model uses a convolution. In the convolution, the integral should run from -infinity to +infinity, but I cant do that. So I always have these boundarie effects from the convolution.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you are trying to do. Are you measuring the convoluted data? Or the concentration directly in some other way?

Comment: The modeled Signal does not drop to zero (the Concentration in red in the 2nd image), but when doing the convolution, the laser pulse is outside of the array of the Concentration, and this will lead to the drop off. Okay maybe I need to include code. I wanted to avoid that since it is rather big and does not make the problem any clearer, I thought. But maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Your function does not look like having two steps in the first place. But in general, do like @noah suggests: make sure the fitting function describes the problem properly (more likely to be a question for sof though). That means including the background and setting the domain properly.

Comment: I am measuring the convoluted data.

Comment: @Martin can't help you with Matlab but with python (scipy.optimize.curve_fit) it is rather trivial - just crop x-values accordingly.

Comment: @Lodinn in the scipy.optimize.curve_fit you mean or before ?

Comment: Your desired function and raw data should look the same. Either define the function so it does not drop off at the end or make sure your data does. What I'd do is to define the stepwise function like bkg + b1 * (np.sign(x - a1)) + b2 * (np.sign(x - a2)) and return the convolution in the curve_fit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133272/discussion-between-lodinn-and-martin).

Comment: One thing that I do not understand is that the fit seems to lie perfectly on top of your concentration, so I'm not really seeing why that is an actual problem. If in your benchmark, your retrieve accurate concentration values, what is the real problem for you? But regardless, it seems that you are convoluting a known and extremely narrow pulse with an unknown function. Because you truncate the signal before reaching the end of your unknown, you can retrieve the data up to the last width of your pulse. That is why it drops off in the last few points, because there is not enough data.

Comment: And the best solution, imo, is to define the function to stop before reaching the end of the data, or in other words, to only evaluate up to ~2-sigma of the probing pulse (or even 3-sigma), where there is still a convolution with something that you can retrieve. At the edge you do not know if you started probing something "new" or not, if you truncated your series.

Comment: @ José Andrade Yes, I was thinking about doing it like that. But it didn't seem to be a nice way to do it, regarding the fitting, because I would give (to scipy curve_fit) an x-Array , that is a different size than the y-Array. This would need to be like that, since my function gives back a smaller array (in length) than the input, since it truncates as you say. Or is that no problem at all ?... I have to check.